# How do you send CartThrob Wishlist contents via email?

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

Looking through the CT Wishlist add-on docs it doesn't say how to email a wishlists contents to another person or email address.

Docs link: http://cartthrob.com/docs/docs_wish-list/#sample-user-flow

I would like to use it for an 'add to quote' feature where certain products (which are not simple products to price) are added to a customers wishlist before they are sent over (via email) to the site owners ready for them to quote by emailing the customer directly.

It says in the docs that it can be done but not how to do it. Can someone please let me know this is definitely possible before purchasing?

Thanks.